# Checking Combines Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have the following combined array in my code:

```
if (($req[$doc_id5] == "Required") && ($signed == "No"))
```

Commands within this IF statement work great if the final document in the array is required and `$signed = No` however I need it to check the entire array for required unsigned documents.

I tried the following:

```
if (in_array("Required",$req[$doc_id5]) && ($signed == "No"))
```

But this did not work.

Happy to post my code if required but it is VERY messy.

EDIT:
Here is the code for checking if a document is signed or not:

```
      $order20 = "SELECT * FROM signatures WHERE doc_id = '$doc_id5' AND action_id = '$action_id' AND member_id = '$member_id'";
      $result20 = mysql_query($order20);

if (mysql_num_rows($result20)>0) {
$signed = "Yes";
} else {
$signed = "No";
}
```

Kind Regards,

n00bstacker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if (in_array("Required",$req) && ($signed == "No"))
```

Second parameter should be an array

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Cheers Prasanth - I think this part solves the problem - but the $signed array also only works off the last value.  Not sure if this is because the [$doc_id5] is removed or if this has always been the case.    The problem is the $signed array cannot reject if there is 1 "No" - only if the document is "Required" and "No".  FYI the other status for a document is "Optional" or "Not Required".  Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Ahh the $signed is a loop not an array.  Is there a way to capture it into an array - then I could combine it with $doc_id5 i believe and do; if `(($req[$doc_id5] == "Required") && ($signed[$doc_id5] == "No"))` could i not?

Comment: I consider your question really messy. I do not know exactly what is the if statement supposed to do (what are your intentions?). Also is there any reason to store Yes and No instead of boolean (true/false)? $signed is a variable not an array according to what you have written. The variable is a loop? what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I am not the greatest at PHP.  Let me explain.  The Yes/No is basically because it is dumped to the screen. Let me give you a scenario.  Engineers in certain fields are required to use Method Statements, but there may be a User Guide that may be useful for them to read but not required for insurance.  Engineers need to sign to confirm they are happy with Method Statement, but don't need to sign to the User Guide.  Basically if the doc_id has a Required status and is Not Signed they will not be able to proceed.  I actually take it back to 1/0 in this IF statement

Comment: And the variable is a loop is me being a n00b - the variable is IN a loop.  In this case there are 2 results.  No then Yes.  No is associated to the Required document and Yes to the Optional document - but because it is taking the last output of $signed and not comparing it to the requirement - it allows the user to proceed